# How can I fix this error about stdClass in PHP

Tags: php, json

This is my code:

```
$array = array(
"Birds" => 
array(
'group' => 1,
"Bird" => array(

array('id' => 1, 'img' => "img1.png", 'title' => "kate"),
array('id' => 2, 'img2' => "img2.png", 'title' => "mary")
)) );


$json = json_encode($array);
echo json_decode($json);
```

OUTPUT IS:

```
//JSON OUTPUT {"Birds":{"group":1,"Bird":[{"id":1,"img":"img1.png","title":"cardinal"},{"id":2,"img2":"img2.png","title":"bluejay"}]}}
```

Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: Can you please reword this question to be somewhat clearer?

Comment: `echo` will attempt to convert its arguments to strings before printing them, which works poorly with arrays and doesn't work at all with certain objects. It's not clear what your objective is here, but if you want to inspect the decoded object, you can use `var_dump` or `var_export` instead of `echo`.

Comment: try print_r($json). and check in which manner it is showing output.

Comment: I want to know why this code produce this error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: @sebi: because you're converting object to string

Comment: var_dump(json_decode($json)); does nothing

Comment: @sebi: `var_dump` always does something

Comment: Thank zerkms, print_r(); instead of echo fixed it, it's not a string so echo doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the second parameter of json_decode as true, more info about these parameters at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

so your `echo json_decode($json);` should be changed to this:

```
print_r(json_decode($json, true));
```

`echo` is changed to `print_r` since the output is an array not a string ...

Comment: Without the true you will receive a stdClass object as output, with the true you will receive an array, that's the difference, you can work with array more easily and you can echo it (You will see Array, but you will not receive that error anymore) ...

Answer (score 1):

try

```
var_dump($json);
```

This allows you to print out the details of objects and other non-primative types.

Echoing is used for strings - Your json decoded string will be an object of type `stdClass`

See `var_dump` http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

See `echo` http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

Answer (score 0):

Use `var_dump` to view variables echo converts your variable to string, while it's object. Also you can add second param to `json_decode($data, true)` to get array instead object, as i assume that's what you want, because input is array.

About object convertion to string you can read  [__toString](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring)